# Looking for C# HTML parser

Tags: c#, .net, html, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

I would like to extract the structure of the HTML document - so the tags are more important than the content.  Ideally, it would be able to cope reasonably with badly-formed HTML to some extent also.

Anyone know of a reliable and efficient parser?