# getting html tags using c#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

ok ive got this code:

```
public static string ScreenScrape(string url)
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        // set properties of the request
        using (System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to filter the text to get the div class="comment" ones
is there another option other than using regular expressions? or is that the only way?

thanks

Comment: This must be a candidate for "most-frequently-duped" question on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841310/html-parser, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c, and finally an exact match (though I disagree with its accepted answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300252/c-best-approach-to-parsing-webpage

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/).

For example:

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
var comments = doc.Descendants("div")
                  .Where(div => div.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "comment");
```

Note that this won't find `<div class="OtherClass comment">`; if you're looking for that, you can call `IndexOf`.

Comment: I've used the agility pack a few times, parses almost anything - completely awesome!

Comment: Note that it won't automatically process entities when reading `InnerText`; you'll need to call `HtmlEntity.DeEntitize` manually.

Comment: Note that there is a new link for [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

Answer (score 1):

HtmlAgilityPack is just a package, that lets you to manipulate html files, however if you want to do screen scrape Selenium WebDriver with PhantomJS is better solution. PhantomJS is headless web browser so it is really fast. Moreover, it has far better functionality compared to html agility pack. There is a short [course](https://www.udemy.com/scraping-and-data-mining-for-beginners-and-pros/?dtcode=ynF0V6s2kfuM) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You shoulnd't use regular expressions to parse HTML - they are the wrong tool for the job, as HTML it too complex for them.
You should use an HTML parser.
See also: 
[Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)

Answer (score 0):

You first port of call should be the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Regular expressions are the classical way to parse this kind of input for non .NET languages.

Additionaly, if you can normalize this to an XML variant (i.e. XHTML), you can use XPATH to query and retrieve the required nodes.

What you do not want to do is implement your own parser.

Comment: **DO NOT PARSE HTML USING Regular Expressions.**  **DO _NOT_ PARSE HTML USING Regular Expressions.**  _DO **NOT** PARSE HTML USING Regular Expressions._   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454