# In C#.net, how can I parse HTML?

Tags: c#, controls, browser

I have a webbrowser control. I navigate it to some address. When it loaded i want to pick only urls from inside this codes. Is it possible to handle the html like xml? If it is possible i can use othe DOM properties too. Any xml like ingredient container object to pass the html into it?
Thank you.

Comment: Din't exactly understand what you are trying to do. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: Yes, i have a little project. On the form there is a webbrowser control. When it loaded with an url, i want to pickup url (<a> tags) addresses and put them into a collection, or write them into a textarea. 
To do these, i would like to use it like xml. Should i then convert the html into xhtml or something else?
Now i am searching on HTML Agility Pack.
Any native methods wellcome.
Thank you
PS: Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need to use the [HTML agility pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

Also see this other stack overflow question:

[C# Is there a LINQ to HTML, or some other good .Net HTML manipulation API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542194/c-is-there-a-linq-to-html-or-some-other-good-net-html-manipulation-api)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [MSHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317(VS.85).aspx) to navigate the DOM. You would need to add a reference to `Microsoft.mshtml` in your project. An example of using it to get all links in a document would be:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;

    foreach (HtmlElement element in doc.Links)
    {
        HTMLAnchorElement link = (HTMLAnchorElement) element.DomElement;
        Debug.WriteLine(link.href);
    }
}
```