# regex catching multiline script tag inside html

Tags: c#, html, regex, tags

I need to grab inline script tags inside html pages.
The regex will eventually be driven from c#.
Now I am using Expresso for test purpose.

The following is the best for now:

```
.*<script.*\r\n(.*\r\n)*\s*</script>
```

i.e.

- `.*<script`  catch the script tag
- `.*\r\n`  catch anything till the end of line
- `(.*\r\n)*` catch other lines of the script
- `\s*</script>` catch the closing script, with any indentation before

It grabs ALL the stuff between the first  tag, inculding html and other script tags.

Comment: You're having a problem parsing HTML with a regular expression? [Colour me surprised](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/424509)!

Comment: If you're going to use this in C# give this a try http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @CanSpice - I thought the popularity of that post would have put an end to "Can I regex my HTML" questions.  Sadly: no.

Comment: Looking back, I found this [interesting post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542194/c-sharp-is-there-a-linq-to-html-or-some-other-good-net-html-manipulation-api).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two scripts on the same line will break your regex. Try it on the source of the page with your question.

Parsing HTML with regex *is not a very good idea* (there is a link in the comment to your question which [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/102112) why *the `<center>` cannot hold*); use HTML parser instead.

The next code snippet selects the `<script>` nodes by using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(html);
var scripts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//script");
```

Isn't this is simplier than regex?

Answer (score 1):

How about enabling "dot matches all" and using something simple:

```
<script\b[^>]*>(.*?)</script>
```

Remember that matching is not the same as capturing. This should capture ($1) what's in between the tags. I did a quick test using http://regexpal.com/

Using bosinski.com/regex in Eclipse (I know it's not C#) here's my test file (followed by results):

```
<html>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
function demoMatchClick() {
  var re = new RegExp(document.demoMatch.regex.value);
  if (document.demoMatch.subject.value.match(re)) {
    alert("Successful match");
  } else {
    alert("No match");
  }
}
// -->
</SCRIPT>
<script language="fred">
this is the second set of code
</script>
</html>
```

Results of the regex match:

```
Found 2 match(es):

start=8, end=275
Group(0) = <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"><!--
function demoMatchClick() {
  var re = new RegExp(document.demoMatch.regex.value);
  if (document.demoMatch.subject.value.match(re)) {
    alert("Successful match");
  } else {
    alert("No match");
  }
}
// -->
</SCRIPT>
Group(1) = <!--
function demoMatchClick() {
  var re = new RegExp(document.demoMatch.regex.value);
  if (document.demoMatch.subject.value.match(re)) {
    alert("Successful match");
  } else {
    alert("No match");
  }
}
// -->

start=277, end=344
Group(0) = <script language="fred">
this is the second set of code
</script>
Group(1) = 
this is the second set of code
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on who you ask, you have different problems. Either your problem is, you use regex on html, or your quantifiers are too greedy.

I don't know your problem you want to solve, but chances are good, that your solution should be to use a html parser.

If you want to stick to regex, then use the ungreedy version of the quantifier `*?`. Your regex would then look something like this

```
.*<script.*\r\n(.*\r\n)*?\s*</script>
```

that means it would match as less rows as needed till the first closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://regex101.com/r/xC0vL8/1)

```
<(?<tag>script*)[^>]*>(?<content>.*?)<\/\k<tag>>
```

Replace the word `script` after `<tag>` with another element name and you can use it for others too.