# How can I get inner html content using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, html, regex

```
<div class="colmask">
  <h1 class="continent_header"><a name="US"></a>US</h1>
    <div class="colmid">
        <div class="colin">
          <div class="colleft">
          .......
          ....... 
          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
   </h1>
 </div>
```

How can I get the inner html of tag  using Regular Expression ?
It means the result will be

```
  <h1 class="continent_header"><a name="US"></a>US</h1>
    <div class="colmid">
        <div class="colin">
          <div class="colleft">
          .......
          ....... 
          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
   </h1>
```

Comment: Don't parse HTML with Regular expressions, use [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843778/regex-catching-multiline-script-tag-inside-html

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use [regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1226652), instead use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

You can achieve what you want via:

```
string elementText = doc.GetElementbyId("ELEMENTID").InnerHtml;
```