# Find indexes in String using multiple search items and one single iteration

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have the following HTML sample document:

```
.....
<div class="TableElement">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th class="boxToolTip" title="La quotazione di A2A è in rialzo o in ribasso?">&nbsp;</th>
        ..
        <th class="boxToolTip" class="ColumnLast" title="Trades più recenti su A2A">Ora <img title='' alt='' class='quotePageRTupgradeLink' href='#quotePageRTupgradeContainer' id='cautionImageEnt' src='/common/images/icons/caution_sign.gif'/></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        ..
        <td align="center"><span id="quoteElementPiece6" class="PriceTextUp">1,619</span></td>
        <td align="center"><span id="quoteElementPiece7" class="">1,6235</span></td>
        <td align="center"><span id="quoteElementPiece8" class="">1,591</span></td>
        <td align="center"><span id="quoteElementPiece9" class="">1,5995</span></td>
        ..
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
......
```

I need to get the values corresponding at quoteElementPiece 6,7,8,9 and 17 (currently further in the document) section.

I am simply searching one by one in the code at the moment:

```
int index6 = doc.IndexOf("quoteElementPiece6");
..
int index17 = doc.IndexOf("quoteElementPiece17");
```

I want to improve this by **scanning in one go** and having all the indexes for the substrings I need. Example:

```
var searchstrings = new string[]
{
    "quoteElementPiece6",
    "quoteElementPiece7",
    "quoteElementPiece8",
    "quoteElementPiece9",
    "quoteElementPiece17"
};

int[] indexes = getIndexes(document,searchstrings); //indexes should be sorted accordingly to the order in searchstrings
```

Is there anything native in .NET doing this (LinQ for istance)?

I know there are HTML Parser libraries but I prefer avoiding using those, I would like to learn how to do this for each kind of document.

Comment: Please show at least what you have googled?.... A simpler search gives this: [C# Is there a LINQ to HTML, or some other good .Net HTML manipulation API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542194/6400526)

Comment: I want to avoid using third party libraries or to parse the whole HTML, the document being an HTML is just an example.

Comment: You can use Linq To XML, but that requires a well formed HTML which you can get using SgmlReader. You might also use HtmlAgilityPack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var words = new []{
    "quoteElementPiece6",
    "quoteElementPiece7"};      
// I take for granted your `document` is a string and not an `HtmlDocument` or whatnot.
var result = words.Select(word=>document.IndexOf(word));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
```

Comment: This works and it's more elegant. But it doesn't perform the scan in one go.

Comment: Then I believe you should look into RegEx but then [you have two problems](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with LINQ. check my solution

```
var doc = "this is my document";
List<string> searchstrings = new List<string>
{
    "quoteElementPiece6",
    "quoteElementPiece7",
    "quoteElementPiece8",
    "quoteElementPiece9",
    "quoteElementPiece17"
};
var lastIndexOfList = new List<int>(searchstrings.Count);

searchstrings.ForEach(x => lastIndexOfList.Add(doc.LastIndexOf(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = @"(?s)<tr class=""odd"">.+?</tr>";
var tr = Regex.Match(html, pattern).Value.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
var xml = XElement.Parse(tr);
var nums = xml
            .Descendants()
            .Where(n => (string)n.Attribute("id") != null)
            .Where(n => n.Attribute("id").Value.StartsWith("quoteElementPiece"))
            .Select(n => Regex.Match(n.Attribute("id").Value, "[0-9]+").Value);
```

Comment: it seems like you are looking for matching tags, but because the `+`is greedy, it does not have to be the case.