# Substring without breaking html c#

Tags: c#, html, regex, substring

Hi guys I'm trying to take a description which has been entered in a wysiwyg editor and take a substring of it..

i.e

```
This is some <span style="font-weight:bold;">text</span>
```

I'd like to limit some descriptions without breaking the html if i just substring and add ...

it breaks the html tags..

I've tried:

```
string HtmlSubstring(string html, int maxlength)
    {
        string htmltag = "</?\\w+((\\s+\\w+(\\s*=\\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\\s]+))?)+\\s*|\\s*)/?>";
        string emptytags = "<(\\w+)((\\s+\\w+(\\s*=\\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\\s]+))?)+\\s*|\\s*)/?></\\1>";

        var expression = new Regex(string.Format("({0})|(.?)", htmltag));
        MatchCollection matches = expression.Matches(html);
        int i = 0;

        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            if (match.Value.Length == 1 && i < maxlength)
            {
                content.Append(match.Value);
                i++;
            }
            else if (match.Value.Length > 1)
            {
                content.Append(match.Value);
            }
        }
        return Regex.Replace(content.ToString(), emptytags, string.Empty);
    }
```

but it doesn't quite get me there!

Comment: Can you guarantee that the input is HTML encoded? Meaning, if a user types a `>` will it already be translated to `&gt;`?

Comment: See this question for how to do html regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) to load the HTML and then get InnerText.

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml("...");
document.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

Also see [C#: HtmlAgilityPack extract inner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785092/c-htmlagilitypack-extract-inner-text)