# Library for reading HTML files as XML (.NET)

Tags: .net, html, parsing

**Duplicate:** [Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser). Please close.

Can you recommend me a library for reading HTML files as XML in .NET? I'd actually prefer to deal with XML objects rather than text. Ideally, it must fix HTML formatting errors.

Comment: I know this. Otherwise I'd use regular XLINQ.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to rethink this.  The two are not equal.

a great example of this is self closing tags.

XML standard indicates that a self closing tag looks like the following:

```
<br/>
```

while html standards has non-content tags as single tags

```
<br>
<link rel="...">
```

In html, using the xml syntax actually is a violation, as `/>` has a different meaning.

There are more examples of these issues in the [following article](http://webkit.org/blog/68/understanding-html-xml-and-xhtml/).

Comment: That's precisely the point of the question - he wants a library that would read HTML, with all its quirks, and expose it as well-formed XHTML. So `<br>` gets translated to `<br/>`, implicitly-closed `<p>` becomes explicitly closed, etc.