# c# find image in html and download them

Tags: c#

i want download all images stored in html(web page) , i dont know how much image will be download , and i don`t want use "HTML AGILITY PACK"

i search in google but all site make me more confused ,

i tried regex but only one result ... ,

Comment: Perhaps you should explain _why_ you don't want to use HtmlAgiliyPack.

Comment: i cant user htmlagilitypack no manual , tut , nothing , so why i use something without any tut ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack

Comment: There's sample code on the title page of the HTMLAgilityPack site - pretty weak excuse for not using it.

Comment: This question are in my opinion formulated so bad, that it is below the stack overflow standard, it should be edited by a moderator, with the original question only added as a history reference. The only reason the post should stay are for the helpful answers.

Answer (score 15):

People are giving you the right answer - you can't be picky and lazy, too. ;-)

If you use a half-baked solution, you'll deal with a lot of edge cases. Here's a working sample that gets all links in an HTML document using [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/33420#52167) (it's included in the HTML Agility Pack download).

And here's a blog post that shows how to [grab all images in an HTML document with HTML Agility Pack and LINQ](http://matthew-marksbury.blogspot.com/2009/07/screen-scraping-with-htmlagilitypack.html)

```
    // Bing Image Result for Cat, First Page
    string url = "http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat&go=&form=QB&qs=n";

    // For speed of dev, I use a WebClient
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string html = client.DownloadString(url);

    // Load the Html into the agility pack
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    // Now, using LINQ to get all Images
    List<HtmlNode> imageNodes = null;
    imageNodes = (from HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img")
                  where node.Name == "img"
                  && node.Attributes["class"] != null
                  && node.Attributes["class"].Value.StartsWith("img_")
                  select node).ToList();

    foreach(HtmlNode node in imageNodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["src"].Value);
    }
```

Comment: if you think im lazy , come here and see how much tabs right now opened :)

Comment: Oh no!!  But but this uses HTML Agility Pack...  The goggles! They do nothing!

Comment: Lazy = posting the question on StackOverflow. Lazy is good!

I've done this kind of thing before and regretted it. HTML Agility Pack deals with weird encoding issues, malformed HTML, etc. If the HTML is under your control and you know it won't change, you can get by with a custom solution; otherwise, leverage what other people have done!

Comment: did you ever used this code ? 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source

Comment: @Charlie - Yes, I'm recommending HTML Agility Pack. The complaint was lack of tutorials; here's some sample code that makes for a good tutorial.

Comment: @Jon - This is the best answer.  I was being facetious :P

Answer (score 5):

First of all I just can't leave this phrase alone:

> images stored in html

That phrase is probably a big part of the reason your question was down-voted twice.  Images are *not* stored in html.  Html pages have references to images that web browsers download separately.

This means you need to do this in three steps: first download the html, then find the image references inside the html, and finally use those references to download the images themselves.

To accomplish this, look at the `System.Net.WebClient()` class.  It has a `.DownloadString()` method you can use to get the html.  Then you need to find all the `<img />` tags.  You're own your own here, but it's straightforward enough.  Finally, you use WebClient's `.DownloadData()` or `DownloadFile()` methods to retrieve the images.

Comment: how about data:image/png;base64?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a WebBrowser control and extract the HTML from that e.g.

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser objWebBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
objWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("your url of html document"));
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument objDoc = objWebBrowser.Document;
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection aColl = objDoc.All.GetElementsByName("IMG");
...
```

or directly invoke the `IHTMLDocument` family of COM interfaces

Answer (score 2):

In general terms

1. You need to fetch the html page
2. Search for img tags and extract the src="..." portion out of them
3. Keep a list of all these extracted image urls.
4. Download them one by one.

Maybe this question about [C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser) will help you a little bit more.

Comment: thanks for ALGORITHM , and i dont want use html agility pack :)