# How to get only files from entire html read in a c# console app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, console-application

I need to get every single file from a URL so then I can iterate over them.

The idea is to resize each image using ImageMagick, but first I need to be able to get the files and iterate over them.

Here is the code I have done so far

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;



namespace Example
{
    public class MyExample
    {

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://www.paz.cl/imagenes_cotizador/BannerPrincipal/";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(html);

                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns the entire html of the URL. However, I just need the files (all images) so I can work with them As I expect.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# find image in html and download them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263266/c-sharp-find-image-in-html-and-download-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at that page, and it's a directory/file list. You can use [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netcore-2.2) to extract all links to images from the body of that page.

Here's a pattern I could think of: `HREF="([^"]+\.(jpg|png))`

Build your regex object, iterate over the matches, and download each image:

```
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("HREF=\"([^\"]+\\.(jpg|png))");
var matches = regex.Matches(html); // this is your html string
foreach(var match in matches) {
   var imagePath = match.ToString().Substring("HREF=\"".Length);
   Console.WriteLine(imagePath);
}
```

Now, concatenate the base url `https://www.paz.cl` with the image relative path obtained above, issue another request to that url to download the image and process it as you wish.

Comment: This worked well, Now the problem is how could I create a directory in that url and then save a copy of each file into it

Comment: Ah, I don't think that's easily possible. That directory is on a remote server. If you have FTP credentials to that server, then you might be able to use some FTP libraries, log in programmatically, and upload the resulting images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [The HTML Agility Pack](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack)

for example

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");

foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["href"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) to load and parse the html page. Then you can extract all the information you need.

```
// TODO add a reference to NuGet package AngleSharp
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
    var address = "https://www.paz.cl/imagenes_cotizador/BannerPrincipal";
    var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
    var document = await context.OpenAsync(address);
    var images = document.Images.Select(img=>img.Source);

}
```

*AngleSharp implements the w3c standard, so it works better than HTMLAgilityPack on real world webpage.*