# Jsoup like parser for C++/C?

Tags: jquery, c++, c, jsoup

Are there any open source Jsoup/jQuery like parser/selector engine for C++/C?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580635/c-sharp-html-css-selector for an answer

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973875/c-html-parser-with-jquery-like-selectors/6973912#6973912). It may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure if that works for C++/C, but there's a .NET port of Jsoup: [Nsoup](http://nsoup.codeplex.com/). See also the comment of [GeReV](http://stackoverflow.com/users/242826/gerev) on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505/how-to-scan-a-website-or-page-for-info-and-bring-it-into-my-program/2835555#2835555).

Answer (score 4):

The newly open sourced c HTML5 parser gumbo-parser from google: https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser

Answer (score -2):

CsQuery and Nsoup are some examples of such parsers or selector engines.

Comment: They are C# libs, not C/C++ as requested