# looking for C# Html parser with CSS selectors

Tags: c#, java, html

right now I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack`.

but it very hard to select by Xpath.

In Java I know `Jsoup`. Is there any .net library that does the same?

parse Html and uses CSS style slectors to find elements.

Comment: What is the problem with XPath, do you have  an example?

Comment: Should be closed as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580635/is-there-a-jquery-like-css-html-selector-that-can-be-used-in-c, not as off-topic

Answer (score 6):

Try [Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/) with HtmlAgilityPack.

Fizzler is:

> A .NET library to select items from a node tree based on a CSS selector. 
>   The default implementation is based on HTMLAgilityPack and selects from HTML documents.

Example from project website:

```
// Load the document using HTMLAgilityPack as normal
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(@"
  <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <p class='content'>Fizzler</p>
          <p>CSS Selector Engine</p></div>
      </body>
  </html>");

// Fizzler for HtmlAgilityPack is implemented as the 
// QuerySelectorAll extension method on HtmlNode

var document = htmlDocument.DocumentNode;

// yields: [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll(".content"); 

// yields: [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>,<p>CSS Selector Engine</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll("p");

// yields empty sequence
document.QuerySelectorAll("body>p");

// yields [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>,<p>CSS Selector Engine</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll("body p");

// yields [<p class="content">Fizzler</p>]
document.QuerySelectorAll("p:first-child");
```

Comment: FIzzler isn't being mantained (no updates since July '09) and has only partial implementation of CSS3, compared to CsQuery's 100% CSS2 and CSS3. CsQuery also indexes documents and is much faster than Fizzler + HAP.

Comment: I would not recommend csQuery due to the number of bugs

Answer (score 2):

You could try this library, which looks very promising to me.
I didn't try it myself, so maybe you wanna share your experience with us if you give that library a try.

Library: CsQuery
Website: https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery
Sample:

```
// get all elements that are first children within 'body' (e.g. excluding 'head')
var childSpans = dom["body"].Find(":first-child");
```

Comment: I would NOT recommend this one cause it have some big problems regarding inheritance. For example you want the 2nd child of the father of the '.myclass [whatever]'...it will fail.

Comment: I would not recommend it also. It has pretty bad bugs that haven't ever been fixed. I have posted in the issue tracker for 2 bugs (It incorrectly matches same elements next to each other, and text() also includes comments)