# Extract data webpage

Tags: c#, .net

Folks,
  I'm tryning to extract data from web page using C#.. for the moment I used the Stream from the WebReponse and I parsed it as a big string. It's long and painfull. Someone know better way to extract data from webpage? I say WINHTTP but isn't for c#..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the webpage is valid XHTML, you can read it into an XPathDocument and xpath your way quickly and easily straight to the data you want.  If it's not valid XHTML, I'm sure there are some HTML parsers out there you can use.

Found a similar question with an answer that should help.
[Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)

Answer (score 5):

To download data from a web page it is easier to use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
string data;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    data = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
}
```

For parsing downloaded data, provided that it is HTML, you could use the excellent [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) library.

And here's a complete example extracting all the links from a given page:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string data = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(data);

            var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
            foreach(HtmlNode link in nodes)
            {
                HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                Console.WriteLine(att.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will you please explain little more