# Regexp that matches all the text content of a HTML input

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex

I have articles on my website which I would like to get corrected and translated automatically. But I need to get the content, without having the HTML tags around.

The idea is to have a regex that could retrieve all the content between the tags (and, if possible, also the content found in tags fields like `<img alt='Little house'>`). The problem is that I don't really know how to write such a regex. Any ideas?

Comment: render the html in a browser and copy the text?

Comment: :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using an [HTML parser](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack), rather than relying on a regex.  Parsing HTML with regex is generally a no-no and are nearly impossible to get right for all cases.  There are many questions here on SO that arrive at the same conclusion.

**EDIT** looks like a couple of us had the same idea...  Also, [here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser) that discusses more parsers.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a regular expression is not the best choice for this job (I will spare you the obligatory tirade).

I would recommend that you look into an HTML parsing library to help you here, something like [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

Answer (score 1):

As people said, regex is not the most recommended way, but if you decide that regex is the way to go, this should get you started:

```
string pattern = @"(<(/?[^>]+)>)"
strippedString = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I have the ability to translate articles on my site into a readers preferred language, I done this using the [Bing translation widget](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/widget/Default.aspx) so I don't do any parsing of html it's all done for me.