# regex removing specified empty xml tag using C#

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I would like to remove tag like the following one with its attributes using C# .Net
how can i do it?

```
<aaa type="1" class="2" />
```

other tags like `<bbb type="5" class="4" />` i would like to keep.

Best Regards,

Comment: Remove it from what? How are you getting the XML document? Show us some code, so we can figure out what you are talking about.

Comment: You can't, not robustly.  XML is not a regular language, and cannot be reliably parsed with regular expressions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875258/regular-expression-to-parse-links-from-html-code/1875281#1875281

Comment: replacing the <aaa type="1" class="2" /> with empty string

Comment: How do you identify which tags you want to remove and which you wish to keep?

Comment: i know them for advance. i can do it with alot of regexs each one for each tag... i don't care...

Comment: @John: But if you don't tell us how to identify which tags you want to remove, it's very difficult to give a specific answer. I can only give a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise against regular expressions for this task.

However you can use LINQ to XML to remove tags with name "aaa" like this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
doc.Descendants("aaa").Remove();
doc.Save("output.xml");
```