# Regex to match if string DOES NOT have more than one period . Matching URL paths that are NOT fully qualified

Tags: c#, .net, regex, url, hyperlink

I've loaded an HTML doc into a string with .NET.  I have this REGEX which I can use to match URLs and replace them, but I need only to match **ONLY** URLs that are **NOT** fully qualified.

If this is my string:

```
djdjdjdjdjdj src="www.example.com/images/x.gif" dkkdkdkdk src="/images/x.gif
```

My result result would look like this:

```
djdjdjdjdjdj src="subdomain.example.com/images/x.gif" dkkdkdkdk src="http://www.example.com/images/x.gif
```

My thinking is I need a REGEX that will match strings that start with `src` or `href` and that do not have more than one period. This Regex matches links that have at least one period so it's not matching them correctly.

```
(src|href)\=(\"(.+?)[\.](.+?)\")
```

Thanks for any info. I'm coding this in C# but only need the REGEX

Comment: Have you considered that there exist domains such as mydomain.co.uk? Could this be an issue for you?

Comment: Don’t use regular expressions for a non-regular language like HTML. Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: If the attribute contains the domain name, it *must* start with "http://" or similar, or else it will be treated as a local (relative) path.  Unless you have a folder in your app named "www.example.com"?  So that's what you really need to look for, not whether the URL contains more than 1 period.  For that matter, what about an intranet scenario where it references http: //myserver/ (no period at all in the domain)?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you try to use something like the HTML Agility parser, as reccomended many times on this site: [Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)

Also it wouldn't hurt to read this [obscure blog entry](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) by some Metallica fan before you start.

Answer (score 1):

Warning : HTML + regex = round peg + square hole

That being said, here's the hammer you requested

```
(src|href)\=(\"[^."]*\.?[^."]\")
```