# C# How to i store website list in xmlnode

Tags: c#, xml, hierarchy, xmlnode

I am trying to store website contents in XmlNode.
my website structure is

> - Site1
>
>   1. List1
>
>      - Folder1
>      - Folder2
>          
>        a] file1
>          
>        b] file2
>      - Folder3
>   2. List2
> - Site2
>
>   1. List1
>   2. List2
> - Site3
>     ...............
> - Site4
>     .........................

So how do i store it in XMLNode. my method should return whole structure as an node ***not as document.***
Thanks in advance.
EDIT: In above case what are the node or element and how to maintain proper hierarchy.

Comment: Why do you not want it as a document? After all, you could us the document's root node for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

can you be more specific waht is the problem if the problem parsing the html or creating the XMLNod. Here is A link that shows creating xml by code ti creates XMLDocument but you can use just tha part that creates the root XMLNode

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/XML/ProgrammaticallycreatinganewXMLdocument.htm

About parsing th html look at this link

[Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you would like to waLk the ´object model´ (your site structure) and build an XML document with this structure.

A recursive function would be an option (pseudo code):

```
BuildRecursiveStructure(SiteStructureNode currentSiteNode, XmlNode buildNode)
{
        newNode = xDoc.CreateElement( currentSiteNode.name );
    buildNode.addChild( newNode );
        foreach (?? childSiteNode in currentSiteNode.Children)
    {
        BuildRecursiveStructure( childSiteNode, newNode );
    }
}

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml("");

BuildRecursiveStrucure( SitesInfoRoot? , xDoc.DocumentElement);
```

Hope this helps,