# Read specific data from XML file

Tags: xml, winforms, c#-4.0

I'm familiar with writing and reading my own XML files like e.g. for setting but I need to read data from a huge xml file but I can't find my starting point.

```
<span class="mw-headline" id="Kader_der_Saison_2010.2F11.5B51.5D">
  Kader der Saison 2010/11 
  <sup id="cite_ref-50" class="reference">
      <a href="#cite_note-50">[51]</a> 
  </sup>
</span>
</h3>
<table class="wikitable" width="550px">
   <tr bgcolor="#DDDDDD">
      <th>Name</th> 
      <th>Trikot</th> 
      <th>Nationalität</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
      <th colspan="3" align="left">Torwart</th> 
   </tr>
   <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
     <td>
         <a href="/wiki/Manuel_Almunia" title="Manuel Almunia">Manuel Almunia</a> 
     </td>
     <td align="center">1</td> 
     <td align="center">
        <span style="display:none" class="sortkey">Spanien !</span> 
        <a href="/wiki/Datei:Flag_of_Spain.svg" class="image" title="Spanier">
           <img alt="Spanier" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9a/Flag_of_Spain.svg/20px-Flag_of_Spain.svg.png" width="20" height="13" class="thumbborder" /> 
        </a>
     </td>
  </tr>
- <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
- <td>
  <a href="/wiki/%C5%81ukasz_Fabia%C5%84ski" title="Łukasz Fabiański">Łukasz Fabiański</a> 
  </td>
  <td align="center">21</td> 
- <td align="center">
  <span style="display:none" class="sortkey">Polen !</span> 
- <a href="/wiki/Datei:Flag_of_Poland.svg" class="image" title="Pole">
  <img alt="Pole" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/Flag_of_Poland.svg/20px-Flag_of_Poland.svg.png" width="20" height="13" class="thumbborder" /> 
  </a>
  </td>
  </tr>
```

As you (maybe) can see i´m trying to read the names of all team members starting next to "Kader_der_Saison" right from the wikipedia.
I need the title or text of these elements

`<a href="/wiki/Manuel_Almunia" title="Manuel Almunia">Manuel Almunia</a>`

to get the names Manuel Almunia, Łukasz Fabiański, etc.

I've tried a a couple of ways, `xmldocument.GetElementById` or Name, `XmlReader.NoteTyp`, `XmlReader.MoveToNextAttribute`, `xmldocument.SelectNode(xpath)`, even tried a linq query on the document but I don't get to the position of the names.

Any ideas how the find the "Kader_der_Saison" position and read the following `<a` link text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like HTML, not XML.  Assuming that is correct, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser).

If it really is Xml (and someone chose really bad tag names), load it in as an XmlDocument or XPathDocument and use XPath navigation to call out the nodes by name.

I don't use XPathDocuments much, but with XmlDocument your code might look something like:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(yourXml)
var nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes(nodeName);
```

Comment: You´re right its a html page i parsed with SgmlReader because i tried to work with nodes (as i mentioned in my question i tried xmldocument.SelectNode(xpath) already).

Answer (score 0):

C# has a really cool class called [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) which essentially turns XML into an object.  It can be a hassle with really deep XML files, because you have to make an object for each node, but I think it's the best thing since sliced bread.

Comment: This one i use to Serialize my own Settings class but how should i use it with the whole wiki site?