# SendMail with Link Received with Error

Tags: c#, .net, email

I have the following function which sends mail. The body of the mail has a link (href) in some cases.

```
    public static void SendMail(string from, string to, string subject, string message,  bool isHTML = true)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(to) && ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["no_mail"] == null)
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(from,
                                                      to,
                                                      subject,
                                                      message);
            string bccAddr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["managementMailAddress"];
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bccAddr))
                mailMessage.Bcc.Add(bccAddr);
            bccAddr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["debugMailAddress"];
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bccAddr))
                mailMessage.Bcc.Add(bccAddr);
            if (isHTML)
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            //mailMessage.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; // avoid 3D?
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailHost"]);

            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

        }
    }
```

Yesterday the mail clients started receiving mails with 3D inserted after the equals sign, and so ceased to work properly.

For example, I see "...href=3Dhttp://..." instead of "...href=http://...".

I made a small change in the code with reference to the BCC list, but nothing that should have a serious effect. The web.config file has not changed, other than putting in various mail addresses in configuration variables.

Why are my links broken?

Comment: did u tried by uncommenting the encoding part?

Comment: Yes, that makes things worse. ):

Comment: remove if(isHTML) condition also and check

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438666/how-to-prevent-html-email-from-having-quoted-printable-when-sending-with-c-sharp

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679213/inlining-css-in-c-sharp

Comment: [link]https://askleo.com/why_does_my_email_sometimes_show_up_with_funny_characters_like_0d_in_it/