# Good way to navigate the DOM

Tags: c#, html, dom

Can I please get some C# code samples on the best way to navigate the DOM? My target data could be buried any where in the node.

I am talking about HTML DOM.

Comment: Which DOM? Which node? Perhaps you are talking about an HTML DOM? It's difficult to answer with this level of detail. Add more info before this gets voted as "not a real question".

Comment: I voted as "not a real question". Now you have provided more info, I'd still vote to close as a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean HTML, I'd go with http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack