# Get location name by giving ZIP codes

Tags: c#, rss, weather, zipcode

I need to display the location and city name when a user enters a ZIP Code. How do I get the corresponding location names?

Comment: Which country? Online or offline? For usage in a product to be sold, or for usage in some kind of in-house software?

Comment: For usage in a intranet website

Comment: for USA. It will be great if it is online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a website like

http://www.zipinfo.com/search/zipcode.htm

and just send the zipcode to that, retrieve the input, parse for the city name, easy as that.

Comment: thanks for the reply. In which format i will get the output from the site?.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by what format. Just a standard format from the website.

Comment: I mean i am developing an .net application, in that user enters zip code, so i need to display the corresponding city name. I will pass the zip code to the above given url. then i need to read the output from the site, for this I asked you in whethar the site send the response in a xml format or any other file?

Comment: No, no file. Just responds with simple HTML. Just as easy to parse as if it gave you a file, maybe even easier.

Comment: @karthik k: you should use the HtmlAgilityPack for this. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978428/parse-a-html-combox-in-c for getting more information.

Comment: THis url is working only 30 trials per day. BUt I want to use it for everyday without limit trials. Do you know any other websites

Comment: @karthikk -- see my answer below for something possibly more acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Try the USPS zipcode API - http://www.usps.com/webtools/welcome.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PlaceFinder](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/) geocoding web service to make [REST based requests](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/requests.html) using the postal code you want to resolve to a name. The service supports both XML and JSON [response formats](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/responses.html). Here is a listing of the [response elements](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/guide/responses.html#result-elements) returned by the service.

Using .NET, you would leverage the client or request/response classes in the [System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btdf6a7e.aspx) namespace to make a request to the service and process the reponse.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use strings. You could alternatively create a ZIP class, if you wanted to get fancy.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    // declare your variable
    private static Dictionary<string, string> zipLookup;

    public static void CreateZips()
    {
        zipLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        zipLookup.Add("90210", "Beverly Hills");
        // fill all other values, probably from a db
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateZips();

        var test  = "90210";

        if (zipLookup.ContainsKey(test))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test.ToString() + "=" + zipLookup[test]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test.ToString() + " location unknown");
        }
    }
}
```

For more details on ZIPs, [check out Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code)

Comment: zipLookup.Add(new KeyValuePair<Zip, string>(90210, "Beverly Hills"); -- here you have given the city name, how come we know that the city name for the particular zip code?

Comment: @karthik k you need to have a lookup. Perhaps you have DB or you look it up online at runtime. The values don't come from thin air, you need to populate them somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

I work in the address verification industry for a company called [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com). The solutions presented here are all functional in a variety of ways, but beware of their limitations and specialties. For example, Yahoo's service is more like address *suggestion*, not *validation*. The USPS web service is quite limited in the results it returns, for example: you won't get the County and Component data of an address, actual deliverability, etc.

For a more flexible, free solution -- may I suggest our [LiveAddress API](http://www.smartystreets.com/Products/LiveAddress-API/)? It's a REST-ful endpoint which, given a street address (for example) and ZIP code, will fully and accurately complete the entire address.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use https://thezipcodes.com/

This has almost all the data that I used for the search.
Use http://thezipcodes.com/docs to use the API.