# How to remove all <a></a> tags from a large html string in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, parsing

I have a large string of HTML that I have parsed with a bunch of already formed links in it. I am looking for a quick way to get rid of all of the links to display just the text. Any help or suggestions is appreciated!

Sample html string looks like this:

```
<A href="test.com">myText</A>, <A href="test1.com">myText</A>, <A href="test2.com">myText</A>, <A href="differenttesturl.com">myText</A>, <A href="test0.com">myText</A>
```

I want the HTML to look like this when it's done:

myText, myText, myText, myText, myText

I'm using C# on an ASP.NET page and have the HTML stored as a STRING,

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags/787951#787951

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution for stripping HTML tags from a string using Regular expressions.

http://www.osherove.com/blog/2003/5/13/strip-html-tags-from-a-string-using-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

You could turn it into an XML document and extract all the Text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an HTML parser to do this.

See this post for some options

[Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)