# Get a value from a webpage c#

Tags: c#, html

I a have a string that contains the code of a webpage.

This is an example:

```html
<input type="text" name="x4B07" value="650"
    onchange="this.form.x8000.value=this.name;this.form.submit();"/>
<input type="text" name="x4B08" value="250"
    onchange="this.form.x8000.value=this.name;this.form.submit();"/>
```

In that string I want to get the `650` and `250` (these are variables and they change value).

How can I do so?

Example:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| x4b08 | 254 |
| x4b07 | 253 |
| x4b06 | 252 |
| x4b05 | 251 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just solved with this

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream st = resp.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st);
string buffer = sr.ReadToEnd();

ArrayList uniqueMatches = new ArrayList();
Match[] retArray = null;
Regex RE = new Regex("name=\"(.*?)\" value=\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.Multiline);
MatchCollection theMatches = RE.Matches(buffer);

for (int counter = 0; counter < theMatches.Count; counter++)
{
//string[] tempSplit = theMatches[counter].Value.Split('"');

Regex reName = new Regex("name=\"(.*?)\"");
Match matchName = reName.Match(theMatches[counter].Value);

Regex reValue = new Regex("value=\"(.*?)\"");
Match matchValue = reValue.Match(theMatches[counter].Value);

string[] dados = new string[2];
dados[0] = matchName.Groups[1].ToString();
dados[1] = matchValue.Groups[1].ToString();
uniqueMatches.Add(dados);
}
```

Tks all for the help

Answer (score 2):

If you were confident that the markup would never change (and you have a simple snippet like your example line) a regex could get you those values, for example:

```
Regex re = new Regex("name=\"(.*?)\" value=\"(.*?)\""); 
Match match = re.Match(yourString); 
if(match.Success && match.Groups.Count == 3){ 
    String name = match.Groups[1]; 
    String value = match.Groups[2];
}
```

Alternatively you could parse the page content and query the resulting document for the elements, and then extract the values. (C# HTML Parser: [Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser) )

Comment: this only return the first element, how can i return the others? for example create a array? ou list?. and the name is return as x8000" type="hidden

Comment: To get multiple name/value pairs from a section of document just carry on with if((match = match.NextMatch()) != null){ name = match.Groups[1]; value = match.Groups[2]; } Check it out in the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Comment: PS: Obviously to create in a list/array or your collection of choice just add the values to that collection as you iterate through. Iteration = Programming 101.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to match `value="([0-9]*)"`

Or you can look for the string "value" using `string.IndexOf` and then take the following few characters.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you (assuming that s contains the string you want to parse):

```
string value = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("value=")+7);
value = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf("\""));
```

Comment: and if i want to get this? name="x4B07" value="650" , name and respective value?

Comment: Regex re = new Regex("name=\"(.*?)\" value=\"(.*?)\""); Match match = re.Match(yourString); if(match.Success && match.Groups.Count == 3){ name = match.Groups[1]; value = match.Groups[2];} - I'm gonna go ahead and add this to my answer so it's more readable!

Comment: Then you will have to make two lines of code to extract the name as well where you take s.IndexOf("name=") + 6 instead of the code written above.

Comment: this only return the first element, how can i return the others? for example create a array? ou list?. and the name is return as x8000" type="hidden

Answer (score 0):

How specific are your examples? Could you also want to extract varying length alphabetic strings? Will the strings you want to extract always be properties?

While the regex/substring way works for the specified examples I think they will scale quite badly.

I'd parse the HTML using a parser (see ndtreviv's answer) or possibly with an XML parser (if the HTML is valid XHTML). That way you will get better control and don't have to bleed your eyes out from fidgeting with a bucketload of regex.

Comment: hi, the page have several name and values, and what i want is something like the example i will insert

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple such controls in the form of string you can create and **XmlDocument** and iterate through it.