# Parsing MHTML File using C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)

Hi Everyone,

I'm using CDO object's createMHTMLBody to download and save the webcontent as MHTML file. 
I want to extract content from that MHTML file using C#. How can i do that.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [HtmlAgility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).