# HTML Parser for C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)

I did some Google search and got a few hits but I wonder whether there is any particular existing code library that stands out from the crowd. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

A tool commonly recommended for this is the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/). It will take HTML and massage it into well-formed XHTML and then a traversable DOM, so is very useful for the code you find in the wild.

There are some examples and the API documentation here:

http://html-agility-pack.net/api

Some useful links:

- [How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)
- [Parsing HTML Documents with the Html Agility Pack](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx)
- [Crawling a web sites with HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.beletsky.net/2010/09/crawling-web-sites-with-htmlagilitypack.html)
- [Getting Started With HTML Agility Pack](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/)