# HTML and JavaScript parser in .NET

Tags: javascript, .net, html, parsing

I'm looking for a HTML and JavaScript parser in .NET.

After reading some posts it seems [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is the best HTML parser approach but it lacks in documentation. I've found some examples of data extraction but almost none of data  transformation.

Where can I find useful samples of data manipulation with HTML Agility Pack and what's the best choice of a JavaScript parser?

Comment: What do you mean by a "JavaScript" _parser?_ Are you trying to check the syntactic validity of your JS code, or actually execute it server-side? And yes, the HTML Agility Pack is [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you 're looking for something like this: http://jint.codeplex.com/
Alternative, I suggest you take a look at Microsoft.JScript: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72bd815a(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Microsoft JScript: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72bd815a(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I would vote for the HTML Agility Pack.  In my experience it doesn't need my documentation if you're familiar with `System.Xml.XmlDocument` -- it has a very similar API.

Sorry but I can't comment on a JS parser.  Perhaps if you explained more about why you want to parse JS I could be of more help.

Comment: Despite the lack of documentation seems to be the best choice.