# Regex Grouping in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have multiple p tags in a HTML code.

```
<p class=MsoNormal><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span
style='font-size:7.0pt'>PA<span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>  </span>ARALIĞI</span></b><span
style='font-size:7.0pt'> [İng. <b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'>PA
interval</b>]. (<i style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'>Kardiyoloji</i>).
Atriyum’un P dalgasının başlangıcını ayıran mesafe. İntraatriyal ya da
sino-nodal iletim süresinin (35-45 milisaniye) ölçümünü verir. Uzaması ileti
bozukluğunun göstergesidir. <o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span
style='font-size:7.0pt'>PA<span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>  </span>ARALIĞI</span></b>        <span
style='font-size:7.0pt'> [İng. <b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'>PA
interval</b>]. (<i style='mso-bidi-font-style:normal'>Kardiyoloji</i>).
Atriyum’un P dalgasının başlangıcını ayıran mesafe. İntraatriyal ya da
sino-nodal iletim süresinin (35-45 milisaniye) ölçümünü verir. Uzaması ileti
bozukluğunun göstergesidir. <o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

How can I get them in a List as different indexes. I need to take each p as a member in the list. My code is :

```
    Regex Rx = new Regex(@"<p(.*)>(.*)<\/p>",RegexOptions.Multiline);
    MatchCollection mc = Rx.Matches(yazi);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a really bad idea to parse HTML with regular expressions. The syntax of HTML is too complex.

Use an HTML parser instead: [Looking for C# HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)