# C# | Regex Dotall and Result Match

Tags: c#, regex

To the point, how i can enable dotall flags on C# Regex ?
And i have this regex.

```
string reg = "<table>.*</table>";
```

And for example, i regexed this html text

```
<table id="table1">
<table id="table2">
</table>
</table>
```

Where does my regex stop the match ? The first `</table>` or the second `</table>`

Thanks guys.. :)

Comment: For the 100th time. DO NOT USE REGEX ON XML/HTML~!

Comment: A more interesting example is `<table id="table1"></table><table id="table2"></table>` - Your regex will match from the first `"<table>"` to the last `"</table>"` (so it will **match nothing** in case of your input - you have attributes). Also, if you have two questions, please post two questions  `:)`

Comment: @leppie, XPATH is not accurate enough..

Comment: Are all the regex questions about how to parse HTML? ;)

Comment: @Aditya Avaga Purwa: Who said anything about XPath?

Comment: @leppie, i'd rather use REGEX rather than Xpath on HTML/XML. Can you give me other resources to search strings or anything in HTML Files accurately ?

Comment: @Aditya Avaga Purwa: Thats like saying you want to use diesel in your petrol car cause diesel smells better. It aint gonna work, buddy!

Comment: @leppie : Give me suggestion for what to use.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are greedy by default, gobbling up as much as possible.   Therefore, it'll stop at the second table.

You can change this by applying the question mark modifier.

```
<table>.*?</table>
```

That said, you'll need to make sure that your regex is set up to cover *multiple lines* of text.

Comment: What about if i have this `<table><table></table></table><table></table>` ? Will its stop at the last or the second ? Or the first ?

Comment: When using `.*?` it will match `<table><table></table>`, so the first `</table>` it finds will end the match. DON'T use regex for this, you want to a proper parser...

Comment: Have to agree with Qtax.  Regex is not the correct solution for parsing markup.  You've demonstrated this with your own example.

Comment: @Qtax: what i want is ,Regex stop at the /table where its started.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Paul Alan Taylor : I want to create HtmlParser Class to get the attributes, element, or anything related to html.

Comment: @Purwa, that's a different question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser

Answer (score 2):

`*` is a 'greedy' operator - i.e. it eats up as much as possible, so it will match between the first `<table>` and the second `</table>` (providing the regular expression is configured to match over multiple lines). You can cause it to be 'non-greedy' by using `*?` instead.

Comment: What about if i have this `<table><table></table></table><table></table>` ? Will its stop at the third or the second ? Or the first ?

Answer (score 0):

Dotall is a regexflag so you can use like:
Regex.Replace(input, regex,  replace, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

Dotall = RegexOptions.Singleline , since it treat the string as a single line.

you can also modify regex flag in the middle of the regex instruction, like in:
(?s)   -   Match the remainder of the pattern with the following effective flags: migs (Multiline, ignorecase, global, and singleline)