# Read tables (content) from Wikipedia using C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I want to read the episode table of each season of a TV show. How can I get the data out of the [wikipedia tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_I_Met_Your_Mother_%28season_1%29#Episodes) using C#? I want to keep my program slim and if possible don't want to use any further dll's or stuff.

Comment: Have you checked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser

Comment: Sounds quite nice, but you got to use a dll for it. I thought about something C# nativ if possible. But thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with importing another assembly to use in your project?

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel; Wikipedia has an [API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aClient_code#.NET).

Answer (score 1):

You must use WebRequest class to get whole page html and then use linq to extract the  tag with class "wikitable"....