# Non mshtml c# parsing html and javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, parsing, html-content-extraction

I'm looking for a way to parse a html document with javascript embedded. I know that this can be done with MSHTML and code DOM, but in this case it is not an option. I need the program to be also able to run on Mono.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser?

Comment: not really. Those just parse html. I need also to parse javascript and for the document to respond to appropriate events.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of HtmlAgilityPack for the HTML parsing, and IronJS for the JavaScript parsing.