# Remove all HTML tags and do a carriage return on <BR> in C#

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I am creating a HTML to text parser. I need to remove all HTML elements and want to do a carriage return everytime there is a `<BR>` and then remove the `<BR>` as well after so there are no HTML tags left. I then want to parse the text for a certain string that is in the combobox. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
private void navigateWeb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        openFD.Title = "Select your configuration file";
        openFD.InitialDirectory = "C:";
        openFD.FileName = "";
        openFD.Filter = "Config File (*.cfg)|*.cfg|Text File (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFD.ShowDialog();
        MyURL = openFD.FileName;
        //Open and read file
        System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
        objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(MyURL);
        richTextBox1.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd();

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(MyURL)
            .Select(l => l.Trim())
            .Where(l => l.StartsWith(comboBox1.Text));
        textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);


    }
```

**************UPDATE**************
Here is the solution that got the job done:

```
 public static string RemoveHTML(string text)
    {
        text = text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ").Replace("<br>", "\n");
        var oRegEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<[^>]+>");
        return oRegEx.Replace(text, string.Empty);

    } 
private void navigateWeb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    openFD.Title = "Enter URL in the box below";
    openFD.InitialDirectory = "C:";
    openFD.FileName = "http://msnconf/configtc.aspx?IP=10.6.64.200&m=c";
    openFD.Filter = "HTTP://|*.*|Config File (*.cfg)|*.cfg|Text File (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";



    //openFD.ShowDialog();
    if (openFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("cancel button clicked");
    }
    else
    {
        MyURL = openFD.FileName;

        webBrowser1.Visible = true;
        richTextBox1.Visible = false;
        permitACL.Enabled = true;


        //webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(MyURL.SelectedItem.ToString()));
        webBrowser1.Navigate(MyURL);
        //Open and read file
        System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
        objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(MyURL);
        richTextBox1.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd();




        //Read all lines of file
        //            String lines = objReader.ReadToEnd();
        String[] crString = { "<BR>&nbsp;" };
        String[] aLines = richTextBox1.Text.Split(crString, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        //            String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(MyURL);
        String noHtml = String.Empty;

        for (int x = 0; x < aLines.Length; x++)
        {
            if(permitACL.Checked)
            {

                if (aLines[x].Contains("permit"))
            {
                noHtml += (RemoveHTML(aLines[x]) + "\r\n");
            }

            }

            if (aLines[x].Contains(comboBox1.Text))
            {
                noHtml += (RemoveHTML(aLines[x]) + "\r\n");
            }
        }

        //Find lines that match our text in the combobox
        //lines.Select(l => l.Trim());
        //.Where(l => l.StartsWith(comboBox1.Text));



        //Print results to textbox
        textBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, noHtml);
    }

}
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use an _existing_ HTML parser? That is, why are you writing your own parser?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser

Comment: I am creating a custom software that handles my business needs without anything extra

Comment: If you found the solution, answer your own question and accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string RemoveHTML(string text)
{
        text = text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ").Replace("<br>", "\n");
        var oRegEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<[^>]+>");
        return oRegEx.Replace(text, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Given that you just removed all tags in line 2, `Replace("<br>"...` isn't going to find very much.

Comment: That's going to fail the first time it sees an HTML comment. i.e. `<!-- <p>hello, world</p> -->`

Comment: Sorry to sound like a such a noob, but how do I use this code?

Comment: `var noHtml = RemoveHTML("<b>bold<\b><br>test");`

Comment: It works, I posted solution in the question section since I don't have ability to answer my own question.

Comment: Also you should use a `StringBuilder` to concat the strings

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - it is an HTML parser that you can query with using XPath syntax.

Comment: I don't know how to use it for my purpose

Comment: @KPS - It comes with documentation and sample projects.