# How to get Links on a web-page using C#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I do have an problem in C# that is
Suppose there is one website's link....`www.xyz.com`and suppose there are 25 links on the website's home page.

Now i want that using C# and asp.net i do have an String array suppose LinkArray[n] and TabArray[n] {string array} and i want that there should be a program which
can list all the links in the array as follows.

suppose links are :
`<a href="xyz.com/home.html">Home</a> <a href="xyz.com/Contact.html"> </a>`
etc

Now i want that in two arrays it should be stored as

```
TabArray[2]= {Home,Contact}
LinkArray[2]={xyz.com/home.html,xyz.com/contact.html}
```

Likewise i want that i can get listed all the links details in of any web page. 
Please suggest me some code/ guide tutorials 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for C# HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sharp-query](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-query/) or [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML. Here's an example with sharp-query:

```
using System;
using XCSS3SE;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var sq = new SharpQuery("http://stackoverflow.com");
        foreach (var el in sq.Find("a[href]"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", el.InnerText, el.Attributes["href"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are hundreds of similar questions with hundreds of similar answer. This post should be closed as dupe.

Comment: I knew it but none of them contains efficient answers and most of them are old [outdapted] so i had to ask it again.